# WolframAlpha, PlotRange function is not working

Tags: wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I'm trying to set the range of the y-axis of a plot in *WolframAlpha* with ***PlotRange***, but it's not working.

Following the examples, if I run (in the input bar in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)):

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

The result is:

> Wolfram|Alpha doesn't understand your query

Why is that? Does this work for you?
Do you know how to solve it, or eventually how can I set the range of the y-axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram|Alpha doesn't quite use strict Mathematica / Wolfram Language syntax.

Try this,

```
plot tan(x), x=-0..10, y=-2..2
```